# How to display Day Counts Timer on Case Object?

Tags: case, formula-field, count

I have a requirement where I want to display no of days when Case is opened. Days should count only when Case Status is 'New','In Progress' or escalated.

IF the case status is Pending with Business or 'On Hold' then it should not count no of Days.If I change the status from Pending or On hold to New or In Progress then it should start the Day Counts Timer.

Scenario 1:

I create a case in Todays Date, Default Status is new, it count the days. If I start to work on the Case Tomorrow and Close it then it gives me exact count which is 1 Day.

Scenario 2:

I create a case in Todays Date, Default Status is new,  If I want to confirm the functionality with business by changing the Status 'Pending With Business' at the same day then it should stop the timer for a while and if business reply back after 2 days and change the Status 'New' or 'In Progress' it should start the timer by showing 1 day not 3 days.

I just want to show no days where I have spent the actual efforts on Case.
Also if I have Business Hours setup in my org say 8 hours for a day and if I work on the case for more than 4 hours then it should count it as 1 day.

Can someone please suggest how much modification I need to achieve this functionality?